# Want to insert data with html tag in mongodb and render it on browser

Tags: html, node.js

I am working on node js with mongoDB. I am able to insert data in database. I have large content to insert with some `<p>` and `<li>` tag. When i am fetching data and rendering it on browser it is showing with tag only. I want that tag to be convert in their meaning.
Example:

```
<p>this is the content</p>
```

It is showing same on browser also.
this should convert in "this is content".

On view page i have following code.

```
    {{#each doc}}
    <div class="content">
    {{this.content}}            
    </div>
    {{/each}}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with MongoDB but with the way you insert the HTML code into the HTML document to be rendered. To get help, you would have to describe how you do this part.

Comment: Assuming you are using `jade`, you need to print the content as raw HTML `!{content}`

Comment: @FlorianWinter : please have a look on my edit.

Comment: @Cyrbil : Are you saying to edit my code as !{{this.content}}??

Comment: What is your templating engine ?

Comment: @Cyrbil: Templating engine is hbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output your content as raw html, or else the template engine will escape your html content.

Look like you are using handlebars: use the triple `{{{ }}}` brackets

```
{{#each doc}}
<div class="content">
{{{this.content}}}            
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great support