# Want to insert data with html tag in mongodb and render it on browser [ejs]

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

This is the same questions as [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065517/want-to-insert-data-with-html-tag-in-mongodb-and-render-it-on-browser), But i want same in ejs.

I am working on node js with mongoDB. I am able to insert data in database. I have large content to insert with some `<p>` and `<li>` tag. When i am fetching data and rendering it on browser it is showing with tag only. I want that tag to be convert in their meaning. Example:

```
<p>this is the content</p>
```

It is showing same on browser also. this should convert in "this is content".

On view page i have following code.

```
index.ejs

<div>
  <%= data.text %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the equal (=) with a (-)

Change this to

```
<div>
  <%= data.text %>
</div>
```

This

```
<div>
  <%- data.text %>
</div>
```